# Problems at install mqseries PHP - Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq, ibm-mq

I'm trying to use the mqseries extension in PHP but I'm in trouble. The error is showing:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mqseries.so' - libmqic.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0*`

The command `dspmqver -a` command shows for me

> Name:        WebSphere MQ
>   Version:     7.5.0.4
>   Level:       p750-004-140807
>   BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
>   Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
>   Mode:        64-bit
>   O/S:         Linux 3.11.0-19-generic
>   InstName:    Installation1
>   InstDesc:    
>   Primary:     Yes
>   InstPath:    /opt/mqm
>   DataPath:    /var/mqm
>   MaxCmdLevel: 750
>   AMQ8351: WebSphere MQ Java environment has not been configured correctly.
>   AMQ8351: WebSphere MQ Java environment has not been configured correctly.
>
> Name:        IBM Global Security Kit for WebSphere MQ
>   Version:     8.0.14.43
>   Build Type:  Production
>   Mode:        64-bit

And the version of the mqseries extension is mqseries 0.14.1. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

MQ version v7.5 is 64-bit, but your connection library is a x86 (32-bit) binary.

Anyway, you can check your libraries:

```
$ file lib/libmqic.so lib64/libmqic.so
lib/libmqic.so:   ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
lib64/libmqic.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

...and you should add the 32-bit library folder (/opt/mqm/lib) to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.